# Animation is very unpredictable with animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

This question is asked a lot of people but I have not really found the answer to it.

I have some class where inside many other methods with animation

```
someClass.m
@implementation

////..

-(void) someAnimationWithSomeObject (someParameters...blablabla

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                          delay:delay
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         self.center = point;
         self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_angle);
     }
                     completion:nil)];
```

in ViewController

```
-(void) someMethod1 {
/.....


for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {

/...some operation with coordinates

        [self.cardContainer addSubview:someView];

        [someView someAnimationWithSomeObject:someParameters withDelay:delay];
        delay += 0.2f; 
/... }
```

[self someMethod2];

```
}

-(void) someMethod2 {
/.....


for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {

/...some operation with coordinates

        [self.cardContainer addSubview:someView];

        [someView someAnimationWithSomeObject:someParameters withDelay:delay];
        delay += 0.2f; 
/... }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self someMethod1];

}
```

When I use this code animation is very unpredictable, because when call `someMethod2` calculation of coordinates is fastest then animation.

how to make the animation to play in the first method and then in the second in etc.

**[solved]**

after someMethod1 adding

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(someMethod2) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

and need some correction with delay + or -

it's well done!

Comment: is `delay` an instance variable or you just created it at beginning of `someMethod2`?

Comment: delay assign by 0 in someMethod1

Answer (score 0):

Consider starting  the second method in the completion block of the first.  That is, "Do this animation; then, when it's finished, call `someMethod2` and start the next animation.